# Texture doesn't fully cover my selected mesh

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm not sure what's going on here. The unwrapped mesh doesn't extend the full length of the face down the side of the can. Is there any way to remap this using nodes?
[image]

[image]

Thanks guys
[image]

Comment: I should also mention that when I unwrapped the selected area, it did not extend the full length of the face in the image editor either.

Comment: The uv wrap is not properly done. It is not fully covering the texture. So scale the texture along y axis in uv editor and try to fit the texture.

Comment: This is what happened when I did that, which is the issue. (referring to the second picture)

Comment: @Feenix Could u explain "vertices in apt materials?" I've applied scale to no avail.

Comment: Are you using a subdivision surface modifier? If so, all you need are some loop cuts to drag it down. The vertices you see in edit mode are not where they really are (if you're using subsurf).

Comment: Try adding an edge loop and bring it down or assign the edge loop vertices after seamed edge loop to the material. uv unwrap again after scaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add a couple of edge loops and drag them down as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In 2.7, enable the *Subdivision Surface* option called *Subdivide UVs*. It will take the modifier effect on the UVmap into account.

In 2.8 the option becomes *Smooth, keep corners*.

[image]